# How to convert Django ORM query to SQL row query?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have Django ORM query:

```
month = InfraVltgDetail.objects.annotate(
        month=TruncMonth('create_dt'))
        .values('month').annotate(
        name_count=Count('id'))
        .values('month', 'name_count')
```

I'm using `month.query` to convert SQL row query.

```
#print(by_month.query)

output:

SELECT django_datetime_trunc('month', "portal_infravltgdetail"."create_dt", 'UTC')
 AS "month", COUNT("portal_infravltgdetail"."id") 
AS "name_count" FROM "portal_infravltgdetail" 
GROUP BY django_datetime_trunc('month', "portal_infravltgdetail"."create_dt", 'UTC')
```

When I'm using output SQL row query to execute but getting error.

How I'm running SQL row query:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test",
        user = "postgres",
        password = "postgres",
        host = "localhost",
        port = "5432")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(output_query)
cur.fetchall()
```

Could you please help me to convert Django ORM to sql.

Comment: You probably did not set the dialect properly, since `django_datetime_trunc`, indeed is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, you are right getting error because of `django_datetime_trunc ` how can fix this.

can i make separate query for it?

Comment: MySQL or Sql Server? Please only tag the correct RDBMS.